# RegEx for removing white space from Dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv, dataframe

I am new to python and I want to remove white space from the data inside the dataframe in python.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please add an example of some data you want to remove whitespaces from? Also, what have you tried so far? Do you have some code others can use as a starting point?

Comment: I have phone number in the format like: 123 45 6 789 I want to remove all the space from this phone number

Comment: firsttable=etl.fromcsv("offices.csv")

Comment: firsttable.columns = map(str.lower, firsttable.columns)

Comment: This question is not very useful if you don't provide any other context.  You should show sample data and the output you desire, along with what you have already tried, what didn't work.  Without this information you get the guessing/back-and-forth in the comments trying to decipher your intent.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of regex:

```py
import re # regex library

phone = "123 45 5 678"
result = re.sub(r"\s", "", phone)
print(result)
```

Without using regex:

```py
print("123 45 5 678".replace(" ", ""))
```

Output in both cases is:

> 123455678

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I expect. I have dataframe with five different columns and I want my code to run for dataframe object not for string.

Comment: data= data.replace('(^\s+|\s+$)', '', regex=True, inplace=True)

Comment: data= data.replace('(^\s+|\s+$)', '', regex=True)

Comment: this above code run without error but still cant get the answer